# 4/3 wire amp rating over distance for sub-panel installation

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

So I have two floors and an attic, the existing connections are pretty terrible, most of the second floor aside from the bathroom is connected on a 12/2 old wire that doesn't even carry ground. The lower floor and basement were all modernized.

I have a lot of devices (computers, TVs, etc.) and I have 3 beds and 2 bathrooms in the second floor. I want them connected over three 20 amp breakers.

I'd like to use a sub-panel and control everything from the second floor itself. The distance between that and the main circuit breaker is about 50ft.

I read about the 4/3 cables and I got a bit confused where some sources say it carries 50amps at 50ft and others say 70 amps over 65ft. The sub-panel is supposed to have a 60 amp breaker, I want to make sure the breaker breaks before the wire feeding it gets too hot. This conflicting information is a bit confusing, if it is the former, then 4 gauge is not good enough, if it's the latter, then I can use it without issues.

Any advice?

Furthermore, I'd like to also feed a 60-amp sub-panel to the attic so I can finish it in the future. Is that too much amperage for a finished attic that will have a kitchen, bathroom and one bedroom?

Comment: The amperage carrying capacity of the wire will depend on the type of wire/cable.  The breaker in the main panel is what protects the wires, not the sub panel breaker, and can be smaller than the one in the sub panel.  The main breaker in the sub panel will work more like a disconnect switch.

Comment: @crip659 I want to use a 4 gauge wire as described in the question. Regarding the breaker, if I have two 60 amp breakers (one in main panel and one in sub, connected by 1 cable), and the cable can't carry the 60 amps to the panel, would the main panel's 60 amp breaker break? Does the cable draw more than 60 at the main circuit breaker end?

Comment: 4 gauge is only the size, but there are different types of wire or cable.  Cable usually are limited in the amps they can carry, compared to wires in conduit, also if the wire is copper or aluminum.  Copper can carry more amps per size/gauge but aluminum is much cheaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't buy any #4 copper wire.  Harper's Rule: Buy the wire *last* (so it is informed by all your research.)

### Volts and amps

First, let's get you up to speed on how North American power works.  Our power delivers 120 volts, *but twice*. [This video covers it pretty well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4).

60 amps is an oddball size that doesn't actually exist in subpanels. 60A subpanels don't exist (they go 30A, 70A, 100A) and 60A *wire* doesn't exist - don't take my word on it, look at Table 310.15(B)(16) (310.16 in NEC 2020) which is the correct table. I think people fixate on 60A because a long time ago, a house might have 60A/110V service. That hasn't been offered for decades. Or 60A is the largest *cheap* breaker.

Note that the subpanel size is "only a redline" like the speed rating on your car tires; you're not *required* to drive 112 MPH or deliver 100A to a 100A-rated panel.

Anyway you figured out from the video that three 120V circuits only need a 40A/240V feeder, even if you don't oversubscribe a bit (which you are allowed to do).   But I am not going to discourage you from putting in plenty of amps - because if you listen to my advice, you're about to make a "quantum leap" into a pricing and availability sweet spot, that will save you a ton of money.

Besides. The future is a thing, and it *loves* electricity :)  You're concerned with fixing your pain points *now*, but if you had plenty of extra capacity in that panel, fair chance you'd find a way to put it to good use. For instance, moving other nearby circuits into it to free space in your main panel.

### Wire choices

Despite scary stories you may have heard, no one ever had a safety issue with large aluminum feeder. The US electrical system is built around the idea of aluminum for the big stuff - even the lugs are made of aluminum (it works better anyway). So I'm advising [2-2-2-4 SER](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/2-3-4-ground-ser-aluminum-building-wire) for an interior run inside the house. It's no more difficult to work with than 4/3 copper, and is 90A instead of 70A. (NM-B is sharply current-limited).

Just FYI, there's also [4-4-4-6 Al SER](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/4-3-6-ground-ser-aluminum-building-wire) at 65A, or [6-6-6-6 SER](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/6-3-6-ground-ser-aluminum-building-wire) at 50A, which is sufficient for your needs today as discussed. But a few people get itchy about aluminum that small; nobody doubts #2.

Now as far as 3 circuits, I'm kinda cringing at *only* three. I gather you were cost-constrained when speccing this, since you weren't up to speed on 240V, oversubscription or aluminum. Bathrooms are legally required to have a dedicated circuit just for counter/workspace receptacles (depending on which sub-rule you use, other bathroom loads can be on that too, but it hurts usability)... and that leaves only 2 for three bedrooms.  I think that is too sparse for a modern home.

I prefer to wire things so each bedroom has access to more than 1 circuit, e.g. on shared walls, serve both bedrooms out of 1 circuit running down that wall (also saves money on wire).  Then a different circuit on different walls, so each bedroom has access to at least 3.  Because inevitably, one room becomes the "tech room" and you have a couple of gaming PCs, an air conditioner (necessarily), laser printer, 3D printer, what have you. *And you don't necessarily know which room that'll be*.  That way, you can scrounge around inside the room and gain access to 3 circuits without having to run extension cords through doorways.

[image]

### That said, to your questions

Thermal overheat for the wires is already accounted for in the electrical code. Table 310.15(B)(16) states the maximum amperage for any given cable. UF and NM cable use the 60C thermal column; all other wire types use 75C column including the type SER I recommend.  There is a ["Round-Up Rule"](https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/next-size-up-rule.119161/) *for feeders* which says if a 65A breaker isn't available you're allowed to use a 70A breaker (but not plan to load the feeder beyond 65A).  How do we determine what a feeder load is? NEC Article 220, preferably section 4. But you can't go wrong by adding breaker handles per phase :)

Now let's talk about *voltage drop*, that's using a larger cable over longer distances to reduce transmission loss.  That is absolutely not a worry until at least 170' in 240V feeder, or 85' in 120V circuits. If you're seeing a table that calls for size bumps much sooner, that's a low-voltage table for automotive/RV/marine.  One such table in particular ranks well in Google and confuses the heck out of many of our askers.

I thought you mentioned something about coordinating the subpanel's main breaker to be the same size as the supply breaker in the main panel.  The subpanel's main is *not actually required*.  Usually when people ask this, they're thinking about what the industry calls "selective coordination" or getting the nearer breaker to trip first. Several thoughts. First, that only exists *as a product* in "over the moon costly" industrial gear. Second, it's rather unlikely if you did your NEC Article 220 Load Calc correctly, and so far you've erred on the side of over-doing it, which is fine.  And third, a tenant must have access to all breakers supplying them and must be able to self-reset any trip (on the off chance this is a rental).

Comment: Thank you for the great answer detailing everything. That aluminum wire looks like a great option. I can run one and have a sub-panel, then use that panel to extend further into the attic in the future. It has more than plenty to take care of the job. 

However, before I do that, I looked at my main panel breaker, it is a 60 amp breaker. The house is old, so this is a relic from old extension. I am not sure what the wire coming in from the electrical company is or whether I can replace that main breaker.

Answer (score 1):

4/3 is a **cable** designation - three 4 AWG **wires** and one ground wire in a common jacket.

The ampacity of the cable depends on the temperature rating and conductor material.

For the NM-B cable type that most inexperienced folks will tend to grab because it's more familiar, the temperature limitation is 60°C and that makes the ampacity 70A for Copper or 55A for Aluminum (far less expensive.) Using wires in conduit or various other types of cable (such as SER) which are rated at 90°C, does not mean the cable or wire-in-conduit can be used at the 90°C ampacities, but using either 90° or 75°C rated cable or wires-in-conduit means you can generally use the 75°C column in the ampacity table, so long as the terminations (on the panel and on the feed breaker) are rated for 75°C, which most are. Those are 85A for copper and 65A for aluminum.

The length you are going is not enough to require an upsize due to length, so you can take those as the numbers to work with for that size wire or cable. But which numbers you have to work with depends on a great deal more than "4/3" - you have to know WHICH 4/3 to know what numbers you need to work with. Choosing the right one (or wires in conduit, which would be three 4AWG wires and one 8AWG copper or 6 AWG aluminum ground,<sup>*</sup> unless using non-flexible metallic conduit that will serve as the ground conductor) will save you money without limiting your capacity.

- *Those ground wire sizes are suitable for up to 100A. Since the 4AWG is somewhat over 60A capacity it could be viewed as "upsized for voltage drop" by a picky inspector which would require this size, rather than the 10 AWG copper or 8 AWG aluminum that up to 60A needs, even though it's a 60A breaker in your plan.*

Answer (score 0):

The circuit size (Amperes) is determined by the breaker at the feed - in this case that is in your main panel.

The wire is sized to be equal to or larger than the minimum required to handle the circuit.

The destination subpanel does not (unless it is in another building) generally have to have a main breaker of its own, but it can have one and often that makes sense. The destination subpanel must be rated to handle at least the feed circuit but can be rated much higher. 60A is a typical subpanel feed size. But that subpanel can itself be a 60A-rated subpanel or a 200A-rated "main" panel or anything in between. The only real difference between a main panel and a subpanel is that the subpanel has to keep neutral and ground separate, which may require some minor changes from an off-the-shelf "main" panel.

60A is typical for the feed breaker. Why? Historically that was the upper limit of inexpensive breakers. Many panels can now have 2-space (rather than more expensive 4-space) breakers that handle more current. But 60A is enough for a typical floor of a house, particularly if it does not include EVSE (a.k.a., car charging), on-demand electric water heating or very large kitchen appliances.

Unless (and actually even *if*) you have a surplus of 4 AWG wire lying around, don't base your actions on the size of the wire. Base the size of the wire on what you actually want to install and the cost of the wire. Aluminum is **much** cheaper than copper. 4 AWG aluminum is good for up to 65A, 3 AWG aluminum 75A and 2 AWG aluminum 90A. If you install conduit and individual wires then oversize the conduit so you can put in larger wires later if needed. If you install cable, you may want to consider 2 AWG instead of 4 AWG if the price is reasonable, which it often is, as that will allow you to upgrade from 60A to 90A in the future if needed.

A subpanel should be as big (in breaker spaces) as you think you need, plus 50%. Think in spaces, not "circuits", as the "n spaces/2n circuits" advertising is based on not requiring AFCI or GFCI but with each version of NEC more circuits require AFCI or GFCI. If you add up all your planned circuits and get 12 spaces, then get a panel with at least 20 spaces. If your circuits add up to 20 spaces then get a panel with at least 30 spaces. That way you don't have to worry about space for future upgrades.

Also keep in mind that a panel (main or sub) needs permanently clear working space - 30" wide x 36" deep, which limits where you can place a subpanel.

Comment: And note that NM-B cables are limited to the 60°C column in the chart, while wires in conduit and SOME other types of cable can use the 75°C column, if the terminations are rated for that (and most will be in this application.) The only use for the 90°C column is for figuring derating, since essentially no devices for household use have terminals rated that high.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I was going to not the NM-B issue, but based on OP stating "4 AWG" and aluminum making sense all around, I ignored copper NM-B.

Comment: People with little experience knee-jerk to buying the stuff because it's familiar. It's a bad knee-jerk.